# Accessing grouped data in dplyr

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

How can I access the grouped data after applying group_by function from dplyr and using %.% operator

For example, If I want to have the first row of each grouped data then I can do this using plyr package as

```
ddply(iris,.(Species),function(df){
  df[1,]
})

#output
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
#2          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#3          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you mean by 'accesing group data'. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I want to access each group after using group_by function from dplyr package and using %.%

Comment: You can add a `summarise(myfun = myfun(column))` to work on the chunk where myfun is a custom function that will work on the chunk. If you turn on `browser`, you'll be able to see the values that are being processed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your specific case, you can use `row_number()`:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %.% 
  group_by(Species) %.%
  filter(row_number(Species) == 1)
## Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
## Groups: Species
## 
##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
## 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
## 2          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
## 3          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica
```

This will be a little more natural in version 0.2 since you can omit the
variable name:

```
# devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")

iris %.% 
  group_by(Species) %.%
  filter(row_number() == 1)
## Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
## Groups: Species
## 
##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
## 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
## 2          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
## 3          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica
```

For arbitrary operations, `do()` is much more useful in 0.2. You give it
arbitrary expressions, using `.` as a placeholder for each group:

```
iris %.% 
  group_by(Species) %.%
  do(.[1, ])
## Source: local data frame [3 x 6]
## Groups: Species
## 
##      Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width  Species.1
## 1     setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
## 2 versicolor          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
## 3  virginica          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found that may help is using the `do` function.

```
library(dplyr)

g.iris <- group_by(x=iris, Species)

do(g.iris, function(x){ head(x, n=1)})
```

Comment: this returns a list if used with %.% operator