# Auto.Arima Loop and Forecast

Tags: r

All, 
I have what seems to be a basic question, but I'm struggling. I'm trying to use Auto.Arima function across two sets of data. There are two tags:

```
GO.DIBTWS003_BATT_VOLT and GO.MIPLES004_BATT_AVE
```

And the data is:

```
                          tag                time value
1  GO.DIBTWS003_BATT_VOLT 2015-08-05 04:00:00  8.51
2  GO.DIBTWS003_BATT_VOLT 2015-08-05 08:00:00  8.51
3  GO.DIBTWS003_BATT_VOLT 2015-08-05 08:15:00  8.46
4  GO.DIBTWS003_BATT_VOLT 2015-08-05 08:30:00  8.51
5   GO.MIPLES004_BATT_AVE 2015-08-05 07:00:00  7.70
6   GO.MIPLES004_BATT_AVE 2015-08-05 08:30:00  7.70
7   GO.MIPLES004_BATT_AVE 2015-08-05 08:45:00  7.59
8   GO.MIPLES004_BATT_AVE 2015-08-05 09:00:00  7.66
9   GO.MIPLES004_BATT_AVE 2015-08-05 09:15:00  7.72
10  GO.MIPLES004_BATT_AVE 2015-08-05 09:30:00  7.72
11  GO.MIPLES004_BATT_AVE 2015-08-05 09:45:00  7.73
```

I would like to run a script to find the best Arima Models for each, and then plot their forecasts. What is th best way to break these two data sets up, run auto.arima, and forecast?

Comment: Noticed I'm getting down voted here. If there is something unclear, please let me know so I can help clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is insufficient information to infer details about your prediction intentions, and assuming knowledge of arima, I will provide a sample code that you might have to adapt to your data and needs:

```
library(dplyr)
preds <-  data %>%    
           group_by(tag) %>%   
           do( {
                xt <- ts( .[,3], frequency=12)
                fit <-     arima(xt ,
                                 order= c(3,0,0),  
                                 method="ML"
                                )
                pred <- forecast(fit, h=12)
                data.frame(.,pred)
              })
```

What you are essentially doing is chaining operations using dplyr's chaining operator %>% .  you can refer to Stackoverflow thread: [Accessing grouped data in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709206/accessing-grouped-data-in-dplyr?rq=1)  for better understanding how do() function works, but essentially, you are passing each subset of data to the do() function. The do function converts the data to timeseries object ( you will have to define frequency to your needs), fits an arima model ( you can put auto.arima() here if you want), then predicts ( again, adapt to your needs), and finally returns predictions. play with to get better understanding.