# Accesing grouped data in dplyr from an outside custom function

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, custom-function

I am trying to write a custom function to pass onto do() in dplyr. The ultimate goal being to use it in addition to group_by() to get my custom function to run on separate chunks of data.

---

Here is what my dataset looks like

```
    > head(data,4)
      subject  ps polarity       rs   log_rs
    1  Danesh 1.0  regular 216.0000 5.375278
    2  Danesh 0.9  regular 285.7143 5.654992
    3  Danesh 0.8  regular 186.3354 5.227548
    4  Danesh 0.7  regular 218.1818 5.385329
```

And the code to generate this dataset:

```
    data <- structure(list(subject = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ChristinaP", 
    "Danesh", "Elizabeth", "Ina", "JaclynT", "JessicaS", "Rhea", 
    "Samuel", "Tyler", "Vinodh"), class = "factor"), ps = c(1, 0.9, 
    0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 
    0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1), polarity = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("regular", "reverse"), class = "factor"), rs = c(216, 
    285.714285714286, 186.335403726708, 218.181818181818, 183.673469387755, 
    194.174757281553, 202.020202020202, 184.615384615385, 153.452685421995, 
    191.693290734824, 216, 285.714285714286, 186.335403726708, 218.181818181818, 
    183.673469387755, 194.174757281553, 202.020202020202, 184.615384615385, 
    153.452685421995, 191.693290734824), log_rs = c(5.37527840768417, 
    5.65499231048677, 5.22754829565983, 5.38532874353767, 5.21315955820773, 
    5.26875856430649, 5.30836770240154, 5.2182746588745, 5.03339228121887, 
    5.25589665066408, 5.37527840768417, 5.65499231048677, 5.22754829565983, 
    5.38532874353767, 5.21315955820773, 5.26875856430649, 5.30836770240154, 
    5.2182746588745, 5.03339228121887, 5.25589665066408)), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, -20L), .Names = c("subject", "ps", "polarity", "rs", "log_rs"))
```

---

And the final call looks like:

```
  temp_df <- data %>%
    group_by (subject, polarity) %>%
    do (customFun(.$ps, .$rs))
```

---

My custom function does a lot of things (that I am skipping here for simplicity), among which calculating the max(rs) on a subset of lines selected based on the value of the variable ps. In other words, I keep only the lines for which ps is either lower than ps of line 2 or larger than ps of line 5, and I calculate the max rs for these selected lines, as in this dummy example:

```
customFun <- function(df, ps, rs) {

   omax = df %>%
       filter (ps < ps[2] | ps > ps[5]) %>%
       summarise (max(rs)) 

  }
```

The problem is that I want to pass this function within a group_by() sub dataframe, so I cannot give a specific name to the dataframe called in my function. Instead, I would like the function to know it should work automatically on the current chunk of data. I tried things like :

```
   omax = . %>%
       filter (ps < ps[2] | ps > ps[5]) %>%
       summarise (max(rs))
```

And many other variations, but nothing seem to work... I found some similar questions online, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709206/accessing-grouped-data-in-dplyr), but still could not figure it out. Any help/hints on how to solve this issue? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551708/r-dplyr-group-by-mutate-how-access-to-the-data-frame)

Custom function:

```
  customFun <- function(df, ps, rs) {
     omax = df %>%
         filter (ps < ps[2] | ps > ps[5]) %>%
         summarise (max(rs)) 
    }
```

Final call:

```
  temp_df <- data %>%
    group_by (subject, polarity) %>%
    do (customFun(., .$ps, .$rs))
```